# How to undo bounty on someone else's question?

Tags: support, bounties

I just dedicated a bounty to someone elses question. But on the second thought, it didn't deserve it. How can I undo my bounty?

Comment: Why not just **improve the question** so that it *does* deserve it? Clearly you want an answer or you wouldn't have set a bounty in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Um, you can, by flagging for moderator attention and *requesting the mod remove the bounty*.

I've removed the bounty you placed [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912888/ispostback-always-returns-false)... ***with my mind.***

Comment: Was this a joke?

Comment: @Fiksdal No.  I removed it with my mind.

Comment: I'm Sheldon Cooper. Could you please clarify?

Comment: OK, I'm not Sheldon Cooper. But did you seriously remove that bounty? (Even if not with your mind.,)

Comment: Hmmm, lemme think back five years... hmmmmmm... nope.  I have no memory whatsoever about what happened here.  If I had to guess, someone else handled it and I just took credit.  Management, here I come!

Comment: OK, so I'm assuming this answer was a total joke.

Comment: @Fiksdal no, the bounty was removed.  If you really REALLY want to know what happened to it, you'll have to flag it and ask a mod to tell you what happened to the bounty.  Five years ago.

Comment: Nope. Not *that* interested.

Answer (score 6):

You can't.

Once a bounty is started, that's it.

Comment: Simple and affirmative. :), why not? How to ask for this feature to be added?

Comment: @Saeed: No. There is no need for such feature. Once offered bounty should not be taken back by owner.

Comment: @Saeed: you can post a separate question as a [meta-tag:feature-request], but I guess you won't get what you ask for, because this behaviour is absolutely by design: it *should* be this way.

Comment: @Saeed, just wait unless bounty is expired - it would not return to you, but also would not make a score to someone else.

Comment: @mhambra - it will be automatically awarded if someone's answer qualifies - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work